# What is the view of Joe Biden on having a balanced budget?

Tags: united-states, budget, joe-biden

As mentioned [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69090/recent-polling-on-u-s-balanced-budget-amendment-or-other) a balanced budget used to have a decent amount of support among the American people. What is the view of Joe Biden on having a balanced budget?

Comment: I would think that adding a reference to his "Build Back Better" plan costing zero dollars could also align with this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone may be able to paint a fuller history here, but interestingly, in 1995 when such a proposal almost passed (close to the 2/3 votes required) Biden had switched his vote in favor, compared to a year before, as LA Times [reported](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1995-02-24-mn-35754-story.html) back then:

> Sens. Joseph R. Biden Jr. of Delaware and Tom Harkin of Iowa, both of whom voted against a similar proposal last year, said they will support the plan when it comes to a vote in the Senate on Tuesday, guaranteeing backers of the amendment at least 64 and perhaps as many as 66 of the 67 votes required for approval. [...]
>
> Biden revealed his decision in a written statement.
>
> “I have concluded that there is nothing left to try except the balanced-budget amendment,” Biden said after reviewing earlier attempts to end the government’s chronic deficit-spending.

Biden [even](https://www.politico.com/newsletters/transition-playbook/2021/03/17/28-trillion-problems-but-the-debt-aint-one-492149) wrote an op-ed in the NYT on that occasion...

> As he wrote in a 1995 New York Times op-ed explaining his position, “trying to spend our way out of recessions is no longer an option.”
>
> Biden went on to write that the amendment "will force the Government to do what it has been unable to do: to spend only the money it takes in, unless extraordinary circumstances force us to find the resources to spend more. I will [vote for the amendment] in the belief that respect for the Constitution will result in a new tradition of fiscal responsibility.”

Biden [did](http://library.cqpress.com/cqalmanac/document.php?id=cqal95-1099955) propose however an amendment (to the would-be constitutional amendment) that would have excepted some investments:

> During the markup, the Republican majority rejected a handful of Democratic amendments, including: [...]
>
> A plan by Joseph R. Biden Jr., D-Del., to allow the government to run deficits to finance major infrastructure projects. Biden argued that this was the practice of most states that operated under balanced-budget strictures. It was tabled by a 12-5 vote.

Also in the same vein:

> Republicans [Feb. 15] easily killed, 59-38, an amendment by Biden to establish a capital budget that would allow the government to run deficits to finance major infrastructure improvements such as highway projects. (Vote 72, p. S-14)